# How many times item into a json

Tags: json, ansible

I have a json file (/tmp/lst_instalaciones_wordpress.json) on a group of servers.
This json has the info about some Wordpress installs (domain, path, version...)

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "My blog",
      "version": "5.9.1",
      "fullPath": "/var/www/vhosts/myblog"
    }
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "My blog2",
      "version": "5.9.2",
      "fullPath": "/var/www/vhosts/myblog2"
    }
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "My blog3",
      "version": "5.7.6",
      "fullPath": "/var/www/vhosts/myblog3"
    }
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "My blog4",
      "version": "5.9.2",
      "fullPath": "/var/www/vhosts/myblog4"
    }
```

I slurped it in a var:

```
    - slurp:
        src: /tmp/lst_instalaciones_wordpress.json
      register: fichero_json

    - set_fact:
        lst_versiones: "{{ fichero_json.content | b64decode | from_json}}"
```

I have a list of all the versions, and I need to print how much installs are for each versions.

```
    all_vers:
      - 5.7.6
      - 5.9.1
      - 5.9.2
```

I'am trying different options like this but nothing works:

```
    - set_fact: 
        all_installs_vers: "{{ lst_versiones | json_query('[?version==`'{{item}}'`].version') | length }}"
      with_items: "{{all_vers}}"
```

Comment: It's neither valid JSON nor YAML. Fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with only one step

```
- set_fact:
    versions: "{{ versions | d({}) | combine({ item.version: nbversion }) }}"
  loop: '{{ lst_versiones }}'
  vars:
    nbversion: >-
            {{ (versions[item.version] | int + 1) if versions[item.version] is defined 
                                                  else (1 | int) }}
```

result if you debug versions:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "5.7.6": "1",
        "5.9.1": "1",
        "5.9.2": "2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the fixed YAML

```yaml
shell> cat tmp/lst_instalaciones_wordpress.yml
---
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "My blog",
      "version": "5.9.1",
      "fullPath": "/var/www/vhosts/myblog"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "My blog2",
      "version": "5.9.2",
      "fullPath": "/var/www/vhosts/myblog2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "My blog3",
      "version": "5.7.6",
      "fullPath": "/var/www/vhosts/myblog3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "My blog4",
      "version": "5.9.2",
      "fullPath": "/var/www/vhosts/myblog4"
    }
]
```

Read the file and decode the list

```yaml
    - slurp:
        src: tmp/lst_instalaciones_wordpress.yml
      register: fichero_json
    - set_fact:
        lst_versiones: "{{ fichero_json.content|b64decode|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
lst_versiones:
  - fullPath: /var/www/vhosts/myblog
    id: 1
    name: My blog
    version: 5.9.1
  - fullPath: /var/www/vhosts/myblog2
    id: 2
    name: My blog2
    version: 5.9.2
  - fullPath: /var/www/vhosts/myblog3
    id: 3
    name: My blog3
    version: 5.7.6
  - fullPath: /var/www/vhosts/myblog4
    id: 4
    name: My blog4
    version: 5.9.2
```

Then, given the list of the versions

```yaml
all_vers:
  - 5.7.6
  - 5.9.1
  - 5.9.2
```

iterate the list, select the version, count the items and combine the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        all_installs_vers: "{{ all_installs_vers|d({})|
                               combine({item: _val|int}) }}"
      loop: "{{ all_vers }}"
      vars:
        _val: "{{ lst_versiones|selectattr('version', 'eq', item)|length }}"
```

gives

```yaml
all_installs_vers:
  5.7.6: 1
  5.9.1: 1
  5.9.2: 2
```